# Connect R-Studio Server installed on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc, rstudio-server

I am trying to connect Free RStudio Server 2023.06.1 Build 524 which is installed on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to SQL Server installed on windows server 2019 datacenter both are on the same network using: `odbc()` package via the following connection string:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "DSN=MySqlServerDSN")
```

and the "DSN=MySqlServerDSN" located in /etc/odbc.ini as follows:

```
[MySqlServerDSN]
Description = My SQL Server Data Source
Driver      = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server      = 192.168.200.100
Port        = 1433
Database    = salesdb
UID         = saun
PWD         = MyDBPassW0rd
```

I am trying to connect it and getting this error

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection.

The thing is I am able to connect from the terminal on R Studio Server using the command

```
isql -v MySqlServerDSN saun 'MyDBPassW0rd'
```

Is there any RStudio Server SSL Configuration I am not aware about?

Thanks

Comment: `isql` uses a different connection library. Do you have `osql` installed? What version(s) of `libssl` do you have installed?

Comment: Since you have access to the target SQL Server 2014 instance by other means what does `SELECT @@VERSION` return? SQL Server 2016 and later have TLS 1.2 support out of the box, but prior versions of SQL Server [require service packs and/or cumulative updates to be installed.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe). Likely your Ubuntu host's OpenSSL libraries are configured to have a minimum TLS 1.2 version requirement and so won't connect to remote hosts that only have TLS 1.0 or 1.1 available.

Comment: `libssl` version is  ` 1.1.1p-1ubuntu2.19`  , osql `Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 17.9.1.0 Linux`

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION` returns :
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
 Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: `12.0.2000.8` is the very original RTM release of SQL Server from 2014-04-01. You'll need to apply updates to it as per the previous link if you want to enable TLS 1.2 support on it.

Comment: ok, so it is not that the RStudio-Server not supporting the SSL and has no certificate as it is free and open source where i found many source suggests that this feature is only available in RStudio-Server Pro! ?

Comment: It's not complaining about the certificate that SQL Server has (it's not even getting to that point), it's complaining about the Ubuntu client and the SQL Server instance having incompatible TLS protocol version support. Seems like you have three options here: 1) turn off SSL/TLS encryption in the DSN's connection properties; 2) downgrade TLS protocol version requirements in Ubuntu's OpenSSL configuration; or 3) upgrade TLS protocol version support on your SQL Server 2014 instance.

Comment: Well, upgrading SQL Server 2014 to SP1 then SP2 solved the problem.

Thanks.